# Custom data validation not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I need to call an ajax method for custom data validation on password field. Here is my code -

.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 20px">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password):    
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password,
                      new
                          {
                              autofocus = "autofocus",
                              autocomplete = "off",
                              @class = "form-control",
                              value = "",
                              data_val_newpassword = "Password does not meet requirements"
                          })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>
```

.js

```
$.validator.addMethod("newpassword", function (value, element) {
    var isValid = false;

    $.ajax({
        url: ccm.resolveUrl('/Home/ValidateNewPassword'),
        data: { password: value },
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        isValid = data.Success;
    });
    return isValid;
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("newpassword");
```

HomeController.cs

```
public JsonResult ValidateNewPassword(string password)
{
    // Validate password against all password requirements.
    var isValid = _passwordValidationService.IsValidPassword(password);

    return Json(new { Success = isValid }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

However, jquery method is not called and thus no ajax request is fired.

Please guide.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it resolved by replacing

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addSingleVal("newpassword");
```

with this -

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("newpassword");
```